# Why is the site.categories array not being output in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I'm building pages (not posts) in Jekyll. One page defines 2 categories in the front-matter as follows:

```
categories: [document, new]
```

And then in a layout I'm trying to output the categories object/array, but nothing is being output:

```
<h1>Array: {{ site.categories }}</h1>
```

Why wouldn't this output an array as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only post's categories are used to populate `site.categories` array.

In a page, the only way to access categories, from the front matter, is  `{% for category in  page.categories %}`. And to scope is restricted to the page itself. :-(

Comment: This is 100% effed.